# convert json to xml and save result to a file

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net

I'm converting a JSON string to an XML node like this:

```
public ActionResult Test(string json)
{ 
    System.Xml.XmlNode myXmlNode = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode("{\"root\":" + json + "}", "root");
```

How can I save myXmlNode  to an external file, say test.xml? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(new StringReader(myXmlNode.ToString()), LoadOptions.None);
xdoc.Save(@"c:\temp\test.xml", SaveOptions.None);
```

UPDATE:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/test.xml")))
{
      writer.WriteLine(myXmlNode.OuterXml);
}
```

Comment: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' when trying to load myXmlNode.ToString()

Comment: Thanks, it's still not working ('Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position' ) but I guess something's wrong with my conversion to xml not with your answer.

Comment: Unless of course your goal is to save the root node as well.  I which case it could be an issue with your deserialization.

Comment: Thanks. This time (after slight modifications) it works! 
using (StreamWriter writer =
        new StreamWriter(Server.MapPath("~/test.xml")))
            {                
                writer.WriteLine(myXmlNode.OuterXml);               
            }

Answer (score 0):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(myXmlNode);

XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter("yourfilename.xml",null);
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
doc.Save(writer);
```